# Use of log() of ServletContext interface

Tags: java

> what is the prcatical use of method **log(String message)** of ServletContext interface?

Answer (score 3):

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#log%28java.lang.String%29

> log
>
> void log(java.lang.String msg)
>
> ```
> Writes the specified message to a servlet log file, 
> usually an event log. The name and type of the servlet
> log file is specific to the servlet container.
>
> Parameters:
>     msg - a String specifying the message to be written to the log file
> ```

Looks to me like it allows you to add messages to the server log.